# LWC: Standard file upload does not update field in file-field-name attribute

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, fileupload

I'm using my LWC to upload photos as Files for a specific Custom Object within a community.

```
<lightning-file-upload label="Upload your photo" record-id={obj.Id} onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished} file-field-name="IsMainPhoto__c" file-field-value="true"></lightning-file-upload>
```

When the user uploads the photo and the handleUploadFinished finishes, the photo is stored as a File of the **obj**, but the field "*IsMainPhoto__c*" is not set to true.

> If it's useful, that community profile has privileges for R and W, and
> View All for the Custom Object.

Can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The API name of the custom field must end with `fileupload__c`.**

Please refer to documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation

Comment: I don't know how I overlooked this point!! Thanks a lot!